# How to apply styles to elements by selecting using class names in angular?

Tags: angular

This is about an angular css styling app.
So as soon as the user applies css styles it gets applied to each element using the renderer2.

Following is a sample key value pair of a style.

```
const style = {key: 'background-color', value: 'blue'}
```

The style and element will be passed by the template (i.e. the above method is called inside the template)

```
<button (click)="setStyle(style, element)">
</button>
```

But I want to query select each element by it's class names then I want to apply the styles as follows:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

}

setStyle(style, element) {
this.renderer.setStyle(document.getElementsByClassName(element.className)[0], style.key, style.value
}
```

But it seems like the above approach is not working.

Is there a way to style an element first by selecting it by class name then styling it?
(or may be adding a class dynamically with the new styles - but remember this class is not already defined in the css rules/ definitions; instead created as we go)

**NOTE** **The main idea is to locate an element by class name and then style it.**

Answer (score 1):

This would not be the correct approach yet there's a solution. My suggestion would be to select elements by **`id`** and not by **class**. By using ID, only a single element would be returned, but by using class, a list of elements would be returned.

> Note: You can add an `if` condition to check for the particular element that you want and then add class to it.

**component.ts file**

```
import { Component, , ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
.
.
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){};

 ngAfterViewInit(){
    const dom: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const elements = dom.querySelectorAll('.class-to-select')
    elements.forEach((domElement)=>{
      domElement.classList.add('myNewClassToAdd');
    })
  }
```

**component.css file**

```
.myNewClassToAdd{
   font-family: monospace;
   color: tomato;
}
```

Hope it helps!!.. Happy Coding!!