# Access parent DOM element

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, dom

I have multiple [Mat dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) components In my project and I want to add styling to just one of them. I'm thinking that the only way to modify **parent** depending on **child** is to add styling to the **DOM** element `<mat-dialog-container>` with the class `.mat-dialog-container`. But when I try to access the parent element by the class `.mat-dialog-container` I can not access it.

According to these examples, this should work?

[How to apply styles to elements by selecting using class names in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/15113491)

[How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516393/15113491)

[image: mat-dialog-container]

**TS:**

```
    export class UpUppdragsloggDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {
        constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UpUppdragsloggDialogComponent>,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: UppdragsloggDialogData,
            private elementRef: ElementRef) {
          }
          ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            const dom: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
// I have also tried to access it with  dom.querySelector('mat-dialog-container'); instead 
            const elements = dom.querySelectorAll('.mat-dialog-container');
            console.log(elements);
            elements.forEach((domElement) => {
              domElement.classList.add('resize-container');
            });
          }

    /** 
    Other not relevant stuff in the component
    */
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
   /* Make dialog components resizeable  */
    .resize-container {
      resize: both; 
      overflow: auto;
      z-index: 5;
    }
```

How to access the **DOM element** for `<mat-dialog-component>` in **Angular**? (I'm using **Angular 10** if it makes any difference.)

Comment: What I know when using Angular, you should avoid to use document.getElementsByClassName(), and use Angulars methods to access the dom element instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know, by using JS/TS, which element is the one you want to style, then you might want to use `element.closest(<selector>)` function. It will give the access to the closest parent container with a specific class. Then you could an additional class to it.

Comment: Thank you!

I know which element I want to style so this works in my case, but I would prefere if there is another way to do this without accessing just the closest parent element..